# How do I password Protect a PDF / Encrypt a PDF in swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, ios-pdfkit

I am trying to export a PDF with a password protection. 
Currently, My app directly exports the PDF File to the iOS Files app...
How do I password protect it before exporting it?

Here's my current code, Please do let me know what I have to change to achive this.

```
func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {

  guard scan.pageCount >= 1 else {


            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
            return
        }



        var arrImages = [UIImage]()
        for i in 0...scan.pageCount-1 {
            let originalImage = scan.imageOfPage(at: i)
            let fixedImage = reloadedImage(originalImage)
            arrImages.append(fixedImage)
        }

        controller.dismiss(animated: true)


        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let docURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("ScannedImage.pdf")


        let data = createNewPDF(arrImage: arrImages)
        do{
            try data?.write(to: docURL)
            print("Success")

        }catch(let error){
            print("error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

The PDF Creation Functions

```
    func createPDF(image: UIImage) -> NSData? {

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        let pdfConsumer = CGDataConsumer(data: pdfData as CFMutableData)!

        var mediaBox = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

        let pdfContext = CGContext(consumer: pdfConsumer, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)!

        pdfContext.beginPage(mediaBox: &mediaBox)
        pdfContext.draw(image.cgImage!, in: mediaBox)
        pdfContext.endPage()
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return pdfData
    }

    func createNewPDF(arrImage: [UIImage]) -> Data? {

        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
        for i in 0...arrImage.count-1 {
            let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: arrImage[i])
            pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage!, at: i)
        }
        let pdfData = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation()

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData!], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return pdfData
    }
```

Please do let me know if you need anything else....
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at his question/answer   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661313/add-a-password-protection-to-an-existing-pdf-file-using-pdfkit-ios

Comment: It doesn't work with the code above...